How to configure Quarkus OIDC to read roles from a custom JWT claim instead of the default "groups" claim?
I am using quarkus:quarkus-oidc and io.quarkus:quarkus-keycloak-authorization with the @RolesAllowed({"APP_ADMIN", ...}) annotation to secure my endpoints.
By default, Quarkus OIDC reads roles from the groups claim in the provided JWT token, but my organization uses a custom claim called roles for this purpose.
Problem:
The roles are being set based on the groups claim (e.g., "JUST:SOME_GROUPS"), but I need Quarkus to use the roles claim instead. I cannot modify the JWT structure in my organization, so I need to configure Quarkus to look at the roles claim.

What I've Tried:
I found the quarkus.oidc.roles.role-claim-path property in the documentation, and I tried setting it to roles and "roles", but neither worked — I've injected the SecurityIdentity to verify this, the roles end up being empty.
Question:
How can I configure Quarkus OIDC to read roles from the roles claim in the JWT, rather than the default groups claim? Is there any additional configuration or custom logic required to achieve this?

Kindly share the code as text rather than a screenshot.

That's just an screenshot of the relevant fields of an exemplary jwt token. This seems to be more of a configuration issue so I dont see any additional value in providing the token itself or an additional code example.

Okay this was mostly an issue with HOW I tested the Problem and partly because of yaml syntax.
I've injected the SecurityIdentity class into an new debugging endpoint which I DID NOT ANNOTATE with @RolesAllowed(...) as I wanted to check the security behavior and what roles are set. I did that because when testing with my other endpoints the debugger didn't activate in my endpoint handling code.
But if a  endpoint is not annotated to be secured, like with @RolesAllowed(...) no claims and roles are setup. So I've shifted my debugpoint to the internal classes (like io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcUtils) that handle claim setup and voila; I could trace the problem.
The configuration attribute quarkus.oidc.roles.role-claim-path is the correct property and must be set to the custom jwt claim object (in my case to "roles"). The property takes an List of elements and if none is found it looks into the "groups" property of the jwt token.
This behavior can be traced with a look into the io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcUtils class and the respective configuration class io.quarkus.oidc.OidcTenantConfig.
In yaml syntax the custom claim object can be set like this:
quarkus:
  oidc:
    roles:
      role-claim-path:
        - "roles"

